# executequeryasync method missing

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have a quite large now program using [Sharepoint] 2013 fondation and CSOM. I use clientcontext.executequery with success.
I would like to work with executequeryasync but my "clientcontext" does not present that method neither in intellisense, nor accepted at compile time if I type it directly. Only executequery is present.
If I "f12" on my clientcontext, I fall in the SP ClientContext class which has an executequery but no executequeryasync.
.Net 4.5 and 4.5.1, same result
What am I missing ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Do you make  sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your code runs?

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', yourFunction);

Comment: I speak about c# and not js. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous version is only available in Silverlight. See the mentioned assemblies in the corresponding [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj168848%28v=office.15%29.aspx).